# Swift and macOS: How to 'tie' my application to another application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I want to let the user 'tie' my application (when running) to one (or several other) application(s) under macOS. The app is a global mouse and tablet manipulating software which is not always appropriate being switched 'on' (in Finder f.i.) at all times. There is a 'Power Toggle' and a Shortcut for activation/deactivation already - but users keep asking. Any hints on how to solve this issue?

Comment: What does your app do, catch events in an event tap?

Comment: Yes, it's listening to events from mouse and tablet devices and  is replacing mouse events using a global CGEventTap (placed at cgSessionEventTap) inside the mechanisms of all its algorithms. These algorithms make use of trigonometric functions or are offsetting the mouse or making it change its normal behaviour somehow. For some algorithms it also makes use of artificial CGEvents.

Comment: What is the question, how to know to which app the event is going?

Comment: Sort of. Hence the application (if activated) sends the modified events to all applications I am seeking for a way to send the events to a specific application (like Photoshop). Or simply deactivate when any other application (except Photoshop f.i.) is in the foreground.

Comment: Did you try `CGEventPostToPid`? Did you try to deactivate?

Comment: None of the above. Yet. I was seeking for a way to tackle this task.